# Active button in WTForms Flask SelectField with dynamic choices

Tags: flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

Im trying to add into the dynamic choices of WTForms Flask SelectField 1 static option.
At this moment I have a category_list, which one works by query in to the db, and include all avaliable choices for each user. I want to add in this selectfield 1 more active option with some action, like a button in bootstrap dropdown with 'href'.
Here is SelectField code in form:

```
class TransactionForm(FlaskForm):
    category = SelectField(coerce=int,
                           validators=[InputRequired()],
                           render_kw={"class": "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle",
                                      "data-toggle": "dropdown",
                                      "aria-haspopup": "true",
                                      "aria-expanded": "false"
                                      }
                           )
```

Would you be so kind to help me find a way to do this, or explain me, why it is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put also the available choices when setting up the Form class.

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    sel = SelectField(coerce=int, label="MyLabel", choices=my_choices)
    ...
```

where choices can be something like this:

```
my_choices = [x.id for x in get_products()]
```

An exception is arised in function `pre_validate` in script `/wtforms/fields/core.py`  when the `validate_on_submit()` functions is called